# Create an identity matrix with scalar in python

Tags: python, numpy

This creates an identity matrix.

```
np.identity(3)
```

```
array([[1.,  0.,  0.],
       [0.,  1.,  0.],
       [0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

But what if I want to multiply with 3I like this?

```
array([[3.,  0.,  0.],
       [0.,  3.,  0.],
       [0.,  0.,  3.]])
```

Comment: `np.identity(3) * 3`

Comment: This is called [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#broadcasting) and appears in the guide [NumPy: the absolute basics for beginners](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html) on numpy.org. It's worth reading this guide to get a feel for the basics of numpy.